# Detection of same function reentrancy vulnerability

Tags: vulnerability

I was reading the detection of same function reentrancy by Zeus tool as discussed in [`http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~joel.reardon/blockchain/readings/ndss2018_09-1_Kalra_paper.pdf`]. They have done cloning. I can’t understand this method. Is this a valid method of testing a smart Contract (SC) because we are modifying the SC? Can we modify the SC during testing?

The paper says:

> Reentrancy in Solidity can happen via the call method. send only
> invokes the default function with limited gas for logging purposes.
> ZEUS handles same-function reentrancy by first cloning the function
> under consideration, and inserting a call to the clone before the
> invocation to call. Fig. 14 shows the patched function for the example
> in Fig. 2. Note that ZEUS ensures that the patch is done within the
> same basic block so as to ensure that if the cloned function is
> called, then the invocation to call is also made. Further, we also
> assert false before the call code. If the verifier finds a path
> leading to this assert, it indicates a bug.

Somebody please help me to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case they verify correctness, defined by the authors as

> adherence to safe programming practices

What they are effectively testing is the root cause of reentrency vulnerabilities: not respecting the CHECK - EFFECT - INTERACTION pattern.

Take their example code:

```
function withdrawBalance() {
    uint amountToWithdraw = userBalances[msg.sender];

    // CHECK
    if (amountToWithdraw > 0) {
        // INTERACTION
        withdrawBalance’();
        msg.sender.call(userBalances[msg.sender]);
        // EFFECT
        userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }
}
```

Which doesn't respect the paradigm, here it is CHECK - INTERACTION - EFFECT. Meaning that a malicious attacker could potentially call `withdrawBalance` from itself by implementing a fallback function that calls `withdrawBalance` again.

The call stack would therefore be :

- WithdrawBalance
- Fallback Function
- WithdrawBalance

Executing `withdrawBalance` twice, so withdrawing twice where it should obvioulsy be forbidden. Their cloning methods artificially creates a path **potentially** allowing a reentrency attack.

> If the verifier finds a path leading to this assert, it indicates a
> bug.

Indeed, if that path can be exploited, there is a vulnerability such as double withdrawal in our example. If the correct programming practices are respected, this path should not be exploitable.

Now take this slightly modified example, same as before but just respecting the CHECK - EFFECT - INTERACTION pattern :

```
function withdrawBalance() {
    uint amountToWithdraw = userBalances[msg.sender];

    // CHECK
    if (amountToWithdraw > 0) {
        // EFFECT
         userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;
        // INTERACTION
        withdrawBalance’();
        msg.sender.call(userBalances[msg.sender]);
    }
}
```

Once again, we have the included call to the clone function but the path it creates is not exploitable, since the rentrency attack would not pass the CHECK step (`if (amountToWithdraw > 0)`) as the EFFECT ( `userBalances[msg.sender] = 0;`) are applied before the INTERACTION step.

> Is this a valid method of testing a smart Contract (SC) because we are
> modifying the SC? Can we modify the SC during testing?

You can see for yourself that it is valid on those example. It does slightly modify the original function flow, and add a gas small gas overhead but it allows for explicit detection of same function reentrency vulnerabilities, which is the intended goal.

As long as your test doesn't change the logic or any invariant of the smart contract, it is perfectly fine. This cloning method doesn't change any of those (at least in this example).

There are examples where this method doesn't work and unintentionally interfere with the smart contract logic / invariants, take a similar function where you expect to be called with X gas, and expect to be left with Y gas before exiting your function or revert, the gas overhead of their detection method would break your contract logic.

It would however be a bad practice, since you should not assume that opcodes gas cost are constant in time. But it shows that this cloning method while mostly correct, is not always correct.

Comment: kindly guide me an instance when the cloning method won't work. Zulfi.